# how can I playing an array of data in BD

Tags: java

how can I create a method to play all the data from an array, and to create a while or for to include all records from this array on BD. Since each recodr is consists two columns in the database table. And i had 1000 records. How do I put this array insert to play giving the BD?
thank you

Comment: What does it mean "BD"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prepared statement (search java.sql.PreparedStatement) to define the generic INSERT statement, and loop on your data to put each specific values for each data, then execute the prepared statement.

Comment: ok.. thanks for you help. I will search about preparedStatement

Comment: you're welcome. I am rofl about something here but I cannot say why, else my account would be deleted...